# Animated desktop in python

Tags: python, animation, desktop

Our school device do not allow customer desktop setup nor software download, so I thought maybe I can write a desktop promgram myself.

I first convert gif/video into separate frams with name 0~(last frame) and stored in Frame directory, then using ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW to set each frame into desktop, and utilized sleep to manipulate the frame rate.

The prblem is that when the frame rate is too fast, or the image resolution is too high, the desktop will become laggy and consumes much of my RAM.
Is there better way manipulate a animated desktop? Please tell ne, Thank you very much!

```
import os, ctypes
from time import sleep

frames = [int(x.split(".")[0]) for x in os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"/Frame")]
frames.sort()

counter = 0
while True:
    desktop_frame = os.getcwd()+"/Frame/"+str(frames[counter])+".png"
    sleep(1/5)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, desktop_frame, 0)
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == len(frames):
        counter = 0
```

Comment: One simple way to solve this is just to reinstall windows, and then you would have admin :)

Comment: Since you're manually sleeping between frames, frame rate shouldn't affect anything. To deal with high-res images, you can add a step where you first go through the folder with images and resize them if they are above a certain size.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would be expelled if I reinstall windows (′゜ω。‵)